# Proper variable scope in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scope, xcopy

I cant figure out this variable scope.. heres the code. I've been reading around but cant seem to nail it. I want to copy a file 4 times and concatenate a name every time expanding the name of the file. it will copy: Cow, Cow Cow, Cow Cow Cow, etc.

```
set "hash = Cow"
call:filecreate "Cow","%hash%"

:filecreate
set "name = %~1"
for /l %%C in (1,1,4) do (
for /f %%a in ('xcopy "%filez%" "%desktop%" /H /Y /R /F') do (
ren "%desktop%\system.ini" "!name!"
)
set "name = !name! %~2"
)
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 3):

SPACES are significant in `SET` statements.

```
set var = something
```

will set a variable `"var "` to `" something"`

```
set var=something
```

will set a variable `"var"` to `"something"`

(also beware - having `CALL`ed `:filecreate`, batch wil then execute `:filecreate` a second time because it does NOT recognise a label as 'end of procedure'. You need an explicit `GOTO :EOF` after the `CALL` if you only want the procedure to be executed once)